# C# - Add A Separating Line In ToolTip a.k.a. <hr>

Tags: c#, controls, tooltip, separator

I would like to add a **horizontal, separating line** in my ToolTip in C#. In HTML it is `<hr>`. What is it in C# for tool tips ? Hope it's possible without overriding.

```
ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
toolTip1.InitialDelay = 0;
toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500;
toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this, "line1\r\n<hr>\r\nline2");
```

Comment: The answers you are getting are basically telling you "no, there is no canned method".  It's just a string, so you will have to format it accordingly (manually).  There is no direct equivalent for `<hr>`.

Comment: Too bad. But I'm not in the mood of overriding. So I'll just leave it away.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Environment.NewLine` in your string, eg.

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this, "Fish" + Environment.NewLine + "Sticks");
```

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I misunderstood. In that case, I would just add ________

Answer (score 0):

As it's a string literal, you can add spaces manually. Just remember that the spaces before `\r\n` won't affect the text so you need to put the spaces before the `line2` part.

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this, "line1\r\n\r\n   line2");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not gonna work without overriding, but if you change your mind then override default tooltip style and put a line or anything you need into the new style.

MSDN example for custom tooltip style: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745107(v=vs.85).aspx
Some fancy example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/creating-fancy-tooltips-in-wpf/